# Как работать с txt файлом в PHP?

Tags: php

Есть текстовой файл в который нужно записывать следующее:

Приходит пост `$_POST['data']` Пост = 1 Это значение я сохраняю в текстовой файл, например приходит следующий пост `$_POST['data']` у которого такое же значение. И мне надо взять с текстового файла единицу, прибавить к ней ту, которая пришла и перезаписать в файл, т.е в файл мы сохраняем 2. В течении дня, таких постов может быть около 500.

Далее хотелось бы приписывать дату сегодняшнего дня, например на следующий день, запись идет на следующей строке. Это трудно сделать?

Меня хватило на это:

```
$file = fopen(TEMPLATEPATH . "/analitic.txt", "w");
$txt = $_POST['data']; //$txt = 1                           
fwrite($file, $txt);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: А ты задумывался над тем что будет если одновременно запустить такой скрипт и одновременно ктото будет читать с того файла а ктото другой писать?...или например 5 чевлоек читает цифру с того файла и в тоже время 10-20 других людей  пишут?......сразу скажу ничего хорошего не будет )))

Comment: Никто не будет ничего писать туда) там просто суммируются еденицы, фишка = сколько раз за день была нажата кнопка, при нажатии приходит еденичка, вот и все)

Answer (score 1):

На работоспособность не проверял, но както так:

```
$filename = "TEMPLATEPATH . "/analitic.txt"";

$num = $_POST['data'];
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    $num = $num + (int)$contents;
}

$file = fopen($filename, "w");                       
fwrite($file, $num);
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я вот так сделал:

```
function my_action_myFunc(){
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $date = date('d.m.Y');
    $file = file_get_contents(TEMPLATEPATH."/analitic.txt",null,null, 10);
    settype($file, "integer");
    settype($data, "integer");
    $a = $file+$data;
    file_put_contents(TEMPLATEPATH."/analitic.txt",$date.PHP_EOL.$a);
    wp_die();
}
```